Выбор библиотеки Python для работы с файлами Excel большого размера
Подскажите какие библиотеки для python хорошо работают с тяжелыми файлами. Я пробовал на openpyxl, при загрузки файла от 130 кб начинает ругаться, что формат файла не поддерживается. При уменьшении объема, того же файла, путем удаления данных, открывается нормально. Какие библиотеки могут работать с файлами в несколько Мб?

Наверное наиболее известная библиотека - pandas. Работает и с excel - чтение из excel. Информации и гайдов по ней можно найти очень много, вот один из первых в выдаче - гайд.
Однако, судя по обсуждениям, ещё сам по себе формат .xlsx не очень хорош для быстрой работы. Здесь можете почитать варианты ускорения работы, например, виртуальный перевод в формат .csv.
Из личного опыта, такой принцип с буфером io.StringIO() я использовал для получения через get-запрос файлов по 100+ Мб и их отправку в БД - уходило по 6-8 секунд на каждый.
